# Java Threading Cyclic Notify() and Wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor

I'm having a code in Java where two objects wait and notify each other when one finished processing. I'll keep my code simple with the following example and assuming there are no syntax error (I just want you to know the logic is more important here rather than the syntax).

Assuming I have object A which is a thread having this pseudo code

```
class A is Thread {
    run() {
        while(true) {
            wait(); // wait for signal from B
            // then do something if signal received
            B.signal(); // let B know that we're done and wait again 
        }
    }
}
```

Then we have here B which is also a thread having this pseudo code

```
class B is Thread {
    run() {
        while(true) {
            // Do something
            A.signal(); // Let A know to continue processing
            wait(); // Wait for signal from A before doing something again
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see there's a cycle. The problem is I am having a dead-lock and the reason here is because when A is finished processing, it signals B to work before it waits.. But by the time B is notified, there are chances that A still haven't reached the wait() code and B is already calling A.signal() and leads to a dead lock.

How do I properly solve this problem? The solution I have in mind is that when B is notified to work, I will let the thread of B sleep for a number of milliseconds but I don't think this is ever a good idea. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is why those methods (`interrupt`, `wait`, `notify`, ...) have a special note in their JavaDoc: **This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor.** In other words - these methods should be called only in `synchronized` block. In that case `notify` won't be called before `wait`.

Comment: @PavelHoral but notify may still be called before any thread is waiting. Thread B should set a flag before calling notify to ensure that Thread A knows that the notification has happened.

Comment: @Pavel yes i know that, but I just tried to short cut the code by removing those synchronized blocks and methods and whatsoever but please focus on the logic.

Comment: The synchronization is pretty important when talking about **thread synchronization** ;). Also I see that you are signaling and notifying different objects (A and B), so that might be one issue with your approach. I would say that the question is a bit too wide to get a proper answer. You should consider adding more information to the *"Do something"* section of your example.

Answer (score 1):

When you use notify() this should be associated with a state change.

When you use wait() this should be associated with a check for a state change.

In real code, you should only wait when you are waiting for something.

Note: wait() can wake spuriously, it doesn't mean notify() was called.  As you noticed, notify() does nothing if nothing is wait()ing.

---

Instead of using this pattern, you can use a BlockingQueue to pass work/messages between threads.  This has the wait/notify and the object containing work built in.

However, since you normally need a thread to do the work, there is an ExecutorService builtin to do this.  This allows you to pass work to a pool of threads and collect the results.

In short, you should be using an ExecutorService.

Answer (score 1):

If A is using the result of B, then maybe you can consider a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you can find described in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()), you need to put your `wait` calls inside a loop that checks for a condition. Otherwise, if you don't have a condition variable or expression that you can check, it is possible that you miss the notify because you were not waiting at that point.

Also, as others have pointed out, you need to hold the monitor of the object you are calling the `wait` or `notify` method on; that's what the `synchronized` keyword is for.

In the below fix, the condition is very simple; it's a variable called `notified` in classes A and B.

Also, to get this right, A and B need to know about each other. In your code you seemed to be invoking static methods; but the `notify` method needs to be called on an instance, so you need to keep references to the instances of A and B in B and A, respectively.

This fixes the problems:

```
class A is Thread {
    private B b;
    private boolean notified;

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            synchronized(this) {
                while (!notified) {
                    try {
                        wait(); // wait for signal from B
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
                notified = false;
            }
            synchronized(b) {
                // then do something if signal received
                b.notified = true;
                b.notify(); // let B know that we're done and wait again 
            }
        }
    }
}

class B is Thread {
    private A a;
    private boolean notified;
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            synchronized(a) {
                // Do something
                a.notified = true;
                a.notify(); // Let A know to continue processing
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                while (!notified) {
                    try {
                        wait(); // Wait for signal from A before doing something again
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
                notified = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```